# Reload a div without creating a nested one with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, load

I was trying to reload a div with jquery using the following code :

```
function reload(param)
{
$("#divId"+param).load(location.href+" #divId"+param);
}
```

Unfortunately, a nested div with the same id is then created inside the first one, causing it hard to delete. I tried this :

```
$("#divId"+param).load(location.href+" #divId"+param+">*","");
```

but then the whole div content is deleted.

Here is my div :

```
<div id="divId">

Random number : <?php echo rand(1,10); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: It should access it if the parameter is empty, as the reply below shows it - tried your code, doesn’t work, but thanks a lot !

Comment: _"but then the whole div content is deleted"_ - `*` is the universal selector, that selects _elements_ of any type. But your `#divId` does not contain _any_ elements.

Comment: Yes you’re right, working well when adding a tag !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this is not working is because your div is empty of tags, so no elements were found inside your div ; try by adding a tag to your text - for instance :

```
<div id="divId">
<p>
Random number : <?php echo rand(1,10); ?>
</p>
</div>
```

Your div should then be correctly reloading when launching `reload("");`

Comment: This is ofc also working with a div or span tag, if you have other structures

Comment: Tried it with a `div` tag, working perfectly, thx !!!

Comment: _'is because you can't let a div "empty"'_ - that phrasing is a bit imprecise. The reason it did not work with `"#divId"+param+">*"` is that `*` would select any _element_, but there weren't any. Introducing one as you suggested solves that problem, but "you can't leave a div empty" as a _general_ statement is just ... not true :-)

Comment: yes indeed, people could ofc let a div empty of tags :) but in this case, this is simply not working - however i'm interested to understand why this didn't work with the `"#divId"+param` alone then